# regexp_substr get last two words from end of the sentence in Oracle SQL

Tags: regexp-substr

I have a string: `ON P6B 0B8`. The output I need is: `P6B OB8`.

I can use `regexp_substr('ON P6B 0B8','[^ ]+$',1)` to get the last word from the end of the sentence. But how would I get the word after the space—the second word from the end?

How do I tell `regexp_substr` to not stop at the first space when looking from behind, and instead move on until it hits the second space?

I had a tough time understanding the metacharacters provided by Oracle regexp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a regex that will get the last 2 sets of characters from your string.  Since it appears you are getting a Canadian postcode though you may want to be a little more careful.

The WITH clause sets up a table with data.  Notice the first row is a valid postcode format, but the second row is bad (2 letters in a row).  Always use unexpected data for your test cases, you don't want any surprises and the data WILL always contain surprises.

The first regex matches 2 sets of 3 characters separated by a space at the end of the string.  At first glance this may seem OK but if the data is bad it will get returned.  To tighten it up, use the second regex, which specifically checks for the Canadian postcode format of uppercase_letter-digit-uppercase_letter-space-digit-uppercase_letter-digit and will return NULL if it is not found.  Maybe you want to catch this with a NVL() call and return a message instead.

```
with tbl(str) as (
  select 'Windsor ON P6B 0B8' from dual union all
  select 'Windsor_bad_postcode ON A3C 9BB' from dual
)
select --regexp_substr(str, '.* (.{3} .{3})$', 1, 1, NULL, 1) postcode_w_bad
       regexp_substr(str, '.* ([A-Z]\d[A-Z] \d[A-Z]\d)$', 1, 1, NULL, 1) postcode
from tbl;
```